# What version of blender approves 441000hz for audio

Tags: startup-file

Im experiencing issues with blender. When i startup the 2.79 version, a black box opens with the Cannot use 441000hz, use 48000hz, so i changed my audio settings and all. Yet, it still doesn't seem to work. im in dire need of using blender for a project im doing. My laptop is an lenovo Ideapad 320. Please help

Comment: I don't thi k it's the sound frequency that is meant by that.

Comment: whats the problem then? cos its impossible for me to figure out

Comment: I would like to know too. I know I had this issue too. I did something that fixed it but I'm sorry, I really cannot remember

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: blender itself. when i start it up, it shows a console black box saying that i cannot use 41000hz and must use 48000hz, which i adjusted but didn't fix anything.

Comment: Ok, let me guess... are you trying to use the Steam version of Blender?

Comment: Hey, look! [I found you on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/1679189548071493117/). See my answer to your question there.