# Failed to set 44100hz, use 48000hz instead

Tags: command-line, startup-file

How do i fix this? Ive used youtube videos and online information but nothing helps. My computer is an Lenovo, Ideapad 330. Its processor is an AMD A9, Radeon R5, 5 compute Cores 2C+3G. It also had 8GB of Ram and 1TB of storage. 
Ive viewed the Help Link for this problem and I have tried everything and nothing changes.

Comment: this a startup issue. I cannot even access the user preferences because blender is not working. And ive adjusted the hz settings and the same information pops up.

Comment: Hi. Please use the [edit] link under your question to add as many details about the problem as possible.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice please https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139138/what-version-of-blender-approves-441000hz-for-audio for any supplemental information edit the first question. For example, state in the question *what actually happens* after console window opens and warning appears in there

Comment: Again - are you using the Steam version of Blender? If so, remove it and use Blender from blender.org. Also, try the zipped version that doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: Hey, look! [I found you on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/1679189548071493117/). See my answer to your question there and also above in the comments.